# Powershell MD5 all file in a folder&subfolder

Tags: powershell, md5

I have writen the following code that can get all files' name in the provided folder and sub-folders. However it is returning this error:

*Resolve-Path : Cannot find drive. A drive with the name '@{Path=C' does not exist.*

```
function Recurse([string]$path) {

  $fc = new-object -com scripting.filesystemobject
  $folder = $fc.getfolder($path)

  foreach ($i in $folder.files) {
    $i | select Path
    $f = $i | select Path   
    Get-FileHash $f
  }
  echo $folder.subfolders
  foreach ($i in $folder.subfolders) {
    Recurse($i.path)
  }
}
Recurse "C:\Users\admin\Pictures"
```

Please give some help with this and I would alot like to know how can I output the result to a txt file.
Thank you so much.

Comment: `echo $f = $i | select Path` what is the `echo` doing on this line? Is this supposed to be an assignment to `$f`?

Comment: Edited the post, I was trying to echo out the $f to check what is its value

Comment: Why are you using COM objects to access the file system?  What's wrong with `Get-ChildItem -Recurse -File -Force`?

Comment: The function worked in my PS 4.0 env.

Comment: I don't see where `Resolve-Path` is in this code. Seeing `A drive with the name '@{Path=C'` tells me that somewhere in your code you have a object with a path property instead of a string

Comment: @ Bacon Bits - Will GetChildItem get files in sub-folders ? I am new to the syntax. Should I do a foreach after the GetChildItem or there are other ways to do it ?